# Bash function return not as expected

Tags: bash, function, return

I have a bash script with a function that is not returning from the function as I think it should.

If the host responds to any of the 3 pings - it should exit the function with a return code 0 - otherwise it would fall out of the loop and exit with a return code 1.

What I find confusing is the trace shows executing the return 0 - but not actually doing it.

I also tried wrapping the ping with a 2nd while loop with a break 2 from the inner "while" but that didn't work as expected either.

What am I missing?

```
#!/bin/bash
pingCheck() {
  ping -c 3 -W 1 $1 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered time= | while read a; do
    return 0
  done
  return 1
}

set -x
pingCheck note5 || exit
...
```

and here is the trace output to a reachable host

```
+ ping -c 3 -W 1 note5
+ grep --line-buffered time=
+ read a
+ return 0
+ return 1
+ exit
```

and here is the trace output to a non-reachable host (works as expected)

```
+ ping -c 3 -W 1 note5x
+ grep --line-buffered time=
+ read a
+ return 1
+ exit
```

Answer (score 4):

The `return 0` statement was associated with `while` loop body, and since when each parts of pipelines in `bash` was run in subshell, the `return 0` cause the subshell executed `while` loop exit, not the entire function.

You can simply drop the `while` part, and using `grep -c`:

```
pingCheck() {
  num_res=$(ping -c 3 -W 1 "$1" 2>&1 | grep -c --line-buffered time=)
  if [ "$num_res" -ne 0 ]; then
    return 0
  else
    return 1
  fi
}
```

---

In some shells like `zsh` and `ksh`, the last part of pipelines was run in current shell, so your function will work in those shells.

Comment: Ah! yes - I came from the old ksh and forgot about the subshell here. I am backgrounding this call to many hosts at once and wish it to return as quickly as possible. If all hosts are up, the "wait" finishes in a 100ms or so without the 2+ second delay for 3 successful pings. Hence, the reason to return on the 1st successful reply.

Answer (score 1):

Or drop everything except ping:

```
pingCheck() {
    if ping -c 3 -W 1 $1 2>&1 ; then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}
```

If you are simply interested in 3-successful pings with no output and a return of `0` on success and `1` on failure, then:

```
pingCheck() {
    if ping -c 3 -W 1 $1 >/dev/null 1>&2 ; then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}
```

**note:** the point made is well taken. Using only `ping` will cause a return on the first failure. So this will confirm `3` successful pings, or a failure of 1 of the 3.

Comment: How about the case when the first two success, the last one fail? At least, you should double quote your variables.

Comment: That is the caveat of using only ping, it will return on the first failure.

Comment: I don't see the `ping` documentation mention about the case, can you give me the reference? As I seen in practice, `ping` won't return on the first failure.

Comment: The return on failure is not a result of a `ping` option, but due to its return value in response to a failure. `-c 3` tells `ping` to return a maximum of `3` responses and `-w` provides a 1 sec timeout in between each response. However, if the network is unreachable `ping` will not receive any response within the 1 second timeout and will exit with a return of 1.

Comment: The if/then/return/else can also be removed altogether since the exit code of the last command is the exit code of the function.